# Codeigniter : Input type number using form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to set input type as number while using form helper.

Following is the code I tried but it did not work for me, Please help me with this.

```
<?php

 $numberfield = array( 'type' => 'number', 'class' => 'form-control qty ' );
 echo form_input('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]', $item['qty'], 'maxlength="3" size="1" style="text-align: right"',$numberfield); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the syntax wrong. You are giving it 4 parameters, while it only accepts at most 3. Those also don't really make sense. Either use array or a string, but not both. According to PHP-rules it will simply ignore the 4th parameter (which is the one in which you specified the input's type)

[You can read the documentation here, it should make it clear, how to correctly use `form_input`.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_input)

Comment: i did this  echo form_input('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]', $item['qty'],$numberfield); ?>
 now it gives me error array to string conversion

Comment: $numberfield = array( 'type' => 'number', 'class' => 'form-control qty ' );

Comment: Then try it with an string? According to the documentation an array should work. You can also look directly at the implementation. It should say mixed, not string. Also I have used it like that and haven't had any problems. Maybe it is with `$item['qty']`? Becauser there only strings are allowed